# Existence of a Hadamard-like matrix

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

**Question**:
For all $n$ large enough, there exists a matrix $A \in [-1,1]^{n \times n}$ such that $A\cdot A$ is a diagonal matrix with each diagonal entry at least $\frac{n}{100}$.

**Discussion**:
When there is a Hadamard matrix of order $n$, we can take $A$ to be that. But when $n$ is not a multiple of 4, there is no Hadamard matrix of order $n$.

Translation to Geometry: Let $B_n(r)$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For all $n$ large enough, there are $n$ orthogonal vectors in $[-1,1]^n \setminus B_n\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{100}}\right)$.

Comment: The hadamard conjecture is unproven but I get your point. I see nothing in the standard bounds to rule out the existence of such a matrix, but cannot think of an obvious construction. Perhaps a probabilistic proof of existence is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use the Discrete Cosine matrix
$$
C=[C_{ij}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n},\quad 
C_{ij}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\cos\left(\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right) 
\left(j-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{n}
\right)
$$
which is symmetric and self inverse, thus
$$
C^\top C=I_n.
$$
Take $A=\sqrt{n/2}\cdot C$ which should satisfy your requirement with each diagonal entry of $A^\top A$ at least $n/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had got the solution from this related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446147/316923).